# What is this line in the middle of nowhere?

Tags: google-maps, maps

Coordinates:https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ramsey+Island/@73.3566979,177.7371323,1017153m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x30fa7771d2910233:0xbf0ed91f32e1737c!8m2!3d12.4930556!4d97.8388889

What is this, is it a rendering failure or a something real?

[image]

Comment: Most likely a rendering failure, since it is situated exactly at 180° west/east.

Comment: Oddly, it looks to be imagery from a different part of the world. Unless I'm mistaken, it looks like sea ice near a coastline. @Erik is probably right that it's a rendering glitch at 180° west/east.